# Symfony method return null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There is a method that takes data from the base value, and outputs it.
If you go through some issues `app.php` - give `NULL`, and when entering through `app_dev.php` - gives the correct **boolen** value.

P.S function name: `isBlocked()`

```
public function indexAction($slug)
{
    $product = $this->get('manager.shop.product')->getBySlug($slug);
    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }
    $this
        ->get('util.breadcrumbs')
        ->add('Catalog', $this->generateUrl('categoryIndex'))
        ->add(
            $product->getShop()->getName(),
            $this->generateUrl('shopIndex', ['slug' => $product->getShop()->getSlug()])
        )->add(
            $product->getName(),
            $this->generateUrl('productIndex', ['slug' => $product->getSlug()])
        );

    $this->get('manager.shop.product')->hit($product, $this->getRequest());

    foreach ($product->getImages() as $image) {
        $this->get('service.image')
            ->create($image)
            ->thumbnailize('525x500-800');
    }


    $shop = $this->get('manager.shop')->getBySlug($product->getShop()->getSlug());
    print_r(var_dump($shop->isBlocked()));

    return $this->render('MashApplicationBundle:Product:index.html.twig', [
        'anotherProducts' => $product->getAnotherShopProducts()->slice(0, 3),
        'product' => $product,
        'shop' => $shop,
     //   'isBlocked' => $shop->isBlocked(),
        'addToCartForm' => $this->createForm('checkout', null, ['data' => ['products' => [$product->getId()]]])->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Try `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: It did not help, issues NULL

Comment: To be more precise: `php app/console --env=prod cache:clear`

Comment: Does not help, give NULL

Comment: Using another cache? eg. Redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve:

```
service memcached restart
```

in SSH